# Using FF "Web Developer" tools. Can you list functions that attached to element events?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

Is there a way for the tool to list the javascript/jquery functions that attach to element events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Firefox 33 and later [does support this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners).

---

In the HTML Pane of the dev tools, you will see an **icon <kbd>ev</kbd> next to elements that have event handlers** bound to them:

[image: elements]

Clicking this icon shows you a list of all event handlers bound to the element:

[image: handlers]

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners)